# Auto-start browser when device is rebooted

Tags: android, browser, autostart

i want to open the browser on reboot. Is there any way i can programmatic invoke the browser without using android code. IS there any web API/Listeners to add for listening the system events like power boot in web APP (browser app) on android device..

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way i can programmatic invoke the browser without using android code.

Not in standard Android. There may be a third-party app that could respond to a boot-completed event and be configured to launch an app of your choice at that point. However:

- That's not really on-topic for Stack Overflow
- It may not work, as the home screen also gets started on a boot

> IS there any web API/Listeners to add for listening the system events like power boot in web APP (browser app) on android device..

No.

Comment: Out of morbid curiosity: Wouldn't it be possible to have a service start up on boot which fires an intent after a period of time?

Comment: @G_V: Yes, but that would violate the "without using android code" bit. My theoretical third-party app could do that. However, determining the right period of time could get a bit interesting.